# C: Getting Segmentation Error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have written this code to get input from a user and save it as a text file.

```
int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("rahiv.txt", "w");
    char s[80];
    char a;
    gets(s);
    a = s ;
    fputs(s, fp);
}
```

But if I want to write the fputs part like below, it's giving me segmentation error, how can I typecast gets() function's return value and fix this!

```
int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("rahiv.txt", "w");
    char s[80];
    fputs(gets(s), fp);
}
```

Comment: What was your intention with `a = s;`? Suggestion: enable all warnings in your compiler, and set it to treat them as errors.

Comment: How do you know the file opened successfully?

Comment: I question the sanity of `a = s ;`, and that pales in comparison to the lack of any sense in using [`gets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) whatsoever, a function so evil and vile it has been *removed* from the standard library years ago. You seem a rather trusting soul, as `fopen` isn't guaranteed to succeed, nor is `gets`, yet you seem to believe both will succeed and never check their results.

Comment: **Never ever use `gets`!** It is not part of the standard and just dangerous. A modern, all recommended warnings enabled compiler will warn. Fix warnings before asking. Use `fgets` instead. And check the result of functions for errors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is some unsafe code. I'll try to address things in order, and hopefully answer your question somewhere in the process.

1) You need to make sure that the file opened successfully. This isn't nice like Java/C#/Python/Other high level languages where it'll throw an exception. You must check `if(fp == NULL) { /*handle error*/ }`

2) You are trying to equate your variables `a` and `s`, which are different types and not equivalent.  `char s[80]` allocates an array of chars 80 bytes long on the stack.  It looks like `s` is of type `char`, but it is actually of type `char*`, so the line `a = s`... well, I'm not sure what it does.

3) `gets` can return more than just the string.  [From the docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/)

> On success, the function returns str. **If the end-of-file is
>   encountered while attempting to read a character, the eof indicator is
>   set (feof). If this happens before any characters could be read, the
>   pointer returned is a null pointer (and the contents of str remain
>   unchanged). If a read error occurs, the error indicator (ferror) is
>   set and a null pointer is also returned (but the contents pointed by
>   str may have changed).**

Trying to pass the return value directly into `fputs` *might* work if you're lucky and everything is correct, but if there is an error, it'll blow up.  In higher level languages, there is a lot of temptation to pass the results of a method straight into the parameter of another method, but in C that often ends badly because there is no try/catch, so errors are often returned as special cases of the return value.  Don't try to make it more compact, favor the longer code and put in all the proper test cases for errors!

4) You never close the file.  Be sure to call `fclose(fp);`, otherwise you'll cause a memory leak and possibly some undesired behavior if your program ever crashes, causing that data you've written to be lost.